# How to increase UItableView Cell and UITextView height based on textlength in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios in my project i have added UItextView on UItableview cell and based on textlength automatically UItextview and UItableview cell height need to increase but according to my code all textdata not displayed on textview some data is missing please help me some one

### This is my code:

```
 formulaArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,finally",nil];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {

        formulaText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        formulaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        formulaText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        formulaText.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        formulaText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:formulaText];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(formulaText);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[formulaText]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

        NSArray * formulaV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[formulaText]-5-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaV];

        formulaText.text = [formulaArray objectAtIndex:0];

        #define kMaxHeight 100.f
        formulaText.contentSize = [formulaText.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0]
                                                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, kMaxHeight)
                                                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        aboutText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        aboutText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        aboutText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        aboutText.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        aboutText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aboutText];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aboutText);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[aboutText]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        NSArray * formulaV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[aboutText]-5-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaV];

        aboutText.text = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:0];
        #define kMaxHeight 100.f
        aboutText.contentSize = [aboutText.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0]
                                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, kMaxHeight)
                                               lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //return 200;

    if([indexPath section] == 0)
    {
        return  200;
    }

    else if([indexPath section] == 1)
    {
        NSString *cellText = [formulaArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }

    else
    {
        NSString *cellText = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }
}
```

But here formula array all text[image] data is not displaying please help me some one

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  - (CGSize )getLabelSizeForString:(NSString *)message      withLabel:(UILabel *)label{
     CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
      return size;
   }
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
NSString *message = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:Message];
CGSize size = [[GlobalConstants sharedInstance] getLabelSizeForString:message withLabel:cell.aboutLabel];

    return size.height;
   }
```

or you may reffer the link
http://www.fantageek.com/1468/ios-dynamic-table-view-cells-with-varying-row-height-and-autolayout/

Comment: With this code we can't increase tableview cell and textview heights dynamically based on textlength

Comment: i did this in my code follow all steps given in link above .

Answer (score 0):

I think this function

```
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

is deprecated in your height ForRowAtIndexPath.

Try to use NSFontAttribute instead of it. In your case it looks like something like that:

```
CGRect textRect = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont}
                                 context:nil];
CGSize labelSize = textRect.size;
```

If you would like to increase it dynamically you need to refresh a specific cell edited. In your

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

You need to refresh your cell.

```
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[yourIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: i want to increase tableview cell and textview height dynamically based on text-length with this code how it's possible

Comment: Ok sorry i'ven't understand your current problem.
If you would like to increase it dynamically you need to refresh a specific cell edited.
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[yourIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return formulaArray.count;
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];


    cell.myTextView.text     = formulaArray[indexPath.row];

    [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

You can easily implement these by storyboard.

1. Drag textview in the cell and add top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint only.
2. Uncheck scrolling enabled for textview.
3. then implement these methods